# WiFi Direct vs Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, wifi-direct

I'm designing a device that needs to interact with smartphones and I need to choose between WiFi Direct and Bluetooth for communication. I don't need high speed, while a higher coverage would be good. I essentially need a serial communication and I already used RFCOMM with Bluetooth. Is it possibile with WiFi Direct or is it more complex?

**What's the best choice looking to the future?**

Answer (score 2):

If you device is battery powered and you don't need high speed, this sounds like a Bluetooth application. If you use [Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) the drawbacks are shorter range (50-100m vs. 200m) and that Bluetooth 4.0 BLE isn't backward compatible.

A good comparison can be seen here:

[Comparison of BLE and WiFi-Direct](http://gtms1313.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/bluetooth4-0-vs-wi-fi-direct/)

Also there are dual chip containing BLE and classical bluetooth:

[See this post for dual chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004171/bluetooth-4-0-with-older-bluetooth)

The future is hard to predict by looking at the past :P